# Writing if conditions in Excel

Tags: excel

I am writing some if conditions in excel and i don`t succeed. I would glad if you can help me.
I want to write the following if condition(Pseudo code):

```
If(L28 appears between C44:C47)
{
Value  = D31
}
else if( L28 ==C48)

{
Value  = D32
}
If(L28 appears between C49:C53)
{
Value  = D30
}
else If(L28 appears between C54:C57)
{
Value  = D29
}
else
{
Value  = L28
}
```

I have written the following part of code, but it is does not work.

```
"=IF(COUNTIF(C44:C47,L28),D31,if(L28=C48,D32,if(COUNTIF(C49:C53,L28),D30,if(COUNTIF(C54:C57,L28),D29))))"
```

Comment: Please clarify "Does not work". Does it give incorrect results? Does it error? Does it crash Excel? Does is make your computer explode...? Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask].

Comment: Yes i get an error, i would glad if you help me creating the if`s condition as excel wants

Comment: You should use match() to do your logical test so: match(L28,C44:C47,0), if it gives a number then take it as true but use iferror to provide false.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this, but I have not tested it:

```
=if(iferror(match(L28,C44:C47,0),0)>0,D31,if(L28=C48,D32,if(iferror(match(L28,CC49:C53,0),0)>0,D30,if(iferror(match(L28,C54:C57,0),0)>0,D29,L28))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a new ifs() function in one of the latest updates.
ifs(condition1, value1, condition2, value2,...) outputs the value for the first condition that is true.
that could simplify the formula a bit.  No more need for nested if().  Below is Solar Mikes solution with ifs().

```
=ifs(iferror(match(L28,C44:C47,0),0)>0,D31,L28=C48,D32,iferror(match(L28,CC49:C53,0),0)>0,D30,iferror(match(L28,C54:C57,0),0>0,D29,L28)
```